# Opening Kendo UI for Angular menu upwards instead of downwards

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

[In this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-84n7kv?file=app/app.component.ts) I have a Kendo UI for Angular context menu. When the user right-clicks the menu list is opened downwards as any regular menu.

What I need is to open the menu list upwards instead of downwards. This is what I'm trying to achieve, forcing the menu always to go up:

[image]

Is this possible? I couldn't find any options in the [API](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/menus/api/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take control in to your hands and specify position on which to open context menu.

First, remove target attribute from context menu item, instead listen to `contextmenu` event on the target.

Secondly, when event handler for contextmenu event is fired, call `show` method in the API and assign correct offset you want to use. Most likely calculating this position based on expected height of the menu will be the trickiest part.

Lastly, prevent default context menu of the browser.

```js
onRightMouseClick(event: MouseEvent) {
  const posX = this.contextMenuTarget.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const posY = this.contextMenuTarget.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top - 85;
  this.contextMenu.show({
    left: posX,
    top: posY
  });

  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<div #target class="target" (contextmenu)="onRightMouseClick($event)">
  <p class="placeholder">Right-click to open Context menu</p>
</div>
<kendo-contextmenu [items]="items" clss="menu"> </kendo-contextmenu>
```

Take a look at the demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-84n7kv-qboo4t).

Comment: it works, however the slide effect is down instead of up, and that look awkward. I tried to disable the effect (I don't need it) with `<kendo-contextmenu  [animate]="false"   ...` but it didn't work, any ideas how to disable the effect?

Comment: There is animate input on the context menu, I believe you can disable animation with that.

Comment: That's what I tried with `[animate=false]`, see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-84n7kv-s9xuvi?file=app/app.component.ts) it's not working

Comment: Use animate=false or [animate]="'false'"

Comment: it doesn't work, sorry, look at the StackBlitz in my previous comment

Comment: just got my hands on laptop, use [popupAnimate]="{ duration: 0, type: 'fade' }"